# How lo align div blocks by the center (no margin)

Tags: html, css

How lo align div blocks by the center . 
I dont need left and right spaces. 
I need clearly code which is align inline element

https://jsfiddle.net/ax7ddqba/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>        
</div>

.wrapper{ 
    border:1px solid red;
    width:980px;
    text-align:center
}

.block{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

I can do like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/yhocvf7p/

```
.wrapper{ 
    border:1px solid red;
    width:980px;
    text-align:left
}

.block{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:240px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:123px;
}

.block:nth-child(3){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

but it's not what I need.

Comment: _but it's not what I need._. Okay, and what you need? Can you show us eg. image what is expected output?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want blocks 1 - 5 to stack horizontally starting in the center of row 1, and when they run out of room at the fourth block, you want block 5 to appear in the center of row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your desired result correctly, which is that the blocks stack horizontally, and then appear in the center of the next row when they run out of room, you should be able to achieve this with `text-align:center` property.

https://jsfiddle.net/y7rtptxr/1/

```
#wrapper {
    border:red 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    width:260px;
}
#wrapper .block {
    background:green;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you can use `font-size: 0;` on your container and then you set needed `font-size` on your children, so you get [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ax7ddqba/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `this`? http://jsfiddle.net/x2pmjkww/